# When update android studio to 3.0 version I get Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: java, android

I have updated Android Studio to version 3.0 and then my app stop working showing the message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Answer (score 0):

In the file build.gradle (app) comment the DEPENDENCIES:

```
//compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
```

And do not forget to add the next line (in the same file)

```
android {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: This is not a general solution to the problem outlined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OkHttp and its urlconnection, change version from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1 like so:

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1"
```

This solved the dex merging problem for me with Android Studio 3 and Gradle 3.